# How to display each value of array per line - IONIC 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Our code is `home.html`

```
<div *ngFor="let Server of Servers; let i = index; let f=first; let l=last;" >
 <p> {{Servers}}</p>
</div>
```

array created in `home.ts` as shown below

```
Servers=['1','2','3'];
```

I want the result on `home.html` page should be like:

```
1
2
3
```

> Please advise.

Comment: did the answer help

Answer (score 1):

It should be,

```
<div *ngFor="let Server of Servers; let i = index; let f=first; let l=last;" >
     <p> {{Server}}</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have included `{{Servers}}` instead of `{{Server}}` in `<p>` tag.

```
<div *ngFor="let Server of Servers; let i = index; let f=first; let l=last;" >
    <!-- Change to this -->
    <p>{{Server}}</p>
    <!-- Change to this -->
</div>
```

Simple example would be :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Servers;" >
    <p>{{item}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most logical solution:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ion-item *ngFor="let Server of Servers; let i = index; let f=first; let l=last;"">
   <p> {{Server}}</p>
  </ion-item> 
</ion-list>
```

Tricky one(not recommended):

```
<div *ngFor="let Server of Servers; let i = index; let f=first; let l=last;" >
 <p> {{Server}}</p>
<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: How to push textbox value in an array and display it on the screen?

Comment: `<ion-input [(ngModel)] = "newValue"></ion-input>
<button (click)="push()"></button>`
`push(){Servers.push(this.newValue)}`